# Can my mother forego Ramadan fasting due to long term illness and old age?

Tags: ramadan, sawm

My mum is living in Bangladesh. She is around 65 years old and has been a suffering diabetic for the last 35 years. She is also suffering from other illness, like shortages of potassium. Alhamdulilllah, she always performed fasting in previous years. In the last 2 or 3 years, we have found some problem: she can complete fasting in Ramadan no problem with that, but after Ramadan her health gets worse. She has to get admission to the hospital which puts the whole family under stress.  This year I told my mum not to fast. If I need to pay to someone to fast behalf of her, I will do it.  Please advise me what can I do in this situation.

Comment: Diabetic should be a reason for her to  not to fast because fasting even could be harmful for her.

Answer (score 2):

**No soul is responsible for that which is beyond its capability** (al-Baqarah 2:233)

Fasting is exempted for those who are in difficult situations, ie. traveling or illnesses/sickness. The following ayat prescribe the alternatives:

**O you who have believed, decreed upon you is fasting as it was decreed upon those before you that you may become righteous**

**...a limited number of days. So whoever among you is ill or on a journey - then an equal number of days. And upon those who can bear it - a ransom of feeding a poor person. And whoever volunteers excess - it is better for him. But to fast is best for you, if you only knew.**

**Month of Ramadan in which was revealed the Quran, a guidance for the people and clear proof and criterion. So whoever sights the month, let him fast it; and whoever is ill or on a journey - then an equal number of other days. Allah intends for you ease and does not intend for you hardship and for you to complete the period and to glorify Allah for that which He has guided you; and perhaps you will be grateful.** (al-Baqara 2:183-85)